# Best way to send a sticker in a xmpp chat

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, chat

i'm looking for a best way to send a sticker using xmpp protocol:

case 1:

user a has a set of sticker downloaded in local storage, he sends a xmpp message with a little preview of sticker as raw data and send a link of the original sticker, user b will see the thumbnail and will download a sticker from url remote

case 2:

user a has a set of sticker downloaded in local storage, he sends a sticker as completely raw data, no url is passed

Any ideas for the best performance?

Answer (score 0):

I think first solution is good one. You send thumb with bad quality and app download the original sticker. It's fast for the sender and for the user who will receive message. I think the same way work telegram.
In second case you have to send big amount of data. It's need more time for both users.